# SonarQube 5.6.1 complexity per class measure failing

Tags: sonarqube

I just upgraded my SonarQube instance to 5.6.1.  I've got a single C# solution being analyzed currently.  I re-analyzed my project and noticed on my dashboard that all of the widgets that were showing me complexity/class aren't working properly.

For example:

TreeMap: I had a treemap where the complexity/class was the size factor, and it now shows me the error message 'treemap.all_measures_undefined'.

Hotspot: I had a hotspot measure that showed me the 10 biggest offenders for complexity/class and now it says "No Data" in design view and just doesn't appear in non-design view.

Complexity: the complexity widget shows me total complexity and complexity per file, but doesn't show me average complexity per class.

Why does complexity per class appear to have fallen off?

SonarQube 5.6.1

C# plugin 5.3.2

MSBuild Scanner 1.1

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, and will be fixed: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-601